# Styling issue on displaying a box outside the container

Tags: css

I'm trying to workout a solution for a problem, that i couldn't solve by my self. Please take a look and tell me what went wrong in this code

```css
.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #eee;
}

.bar .progress {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4ece99;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.bar .progress span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -28px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 28px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid #345;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
}



.bar2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #eee;
}

.bar2 .progress {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4ece99;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.bar2 .progress span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -28px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 28px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid #345;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
Current: 
<div class="bar">
  <div class="progress" style="width: 50%">
    <span>50</span>
  </div>
</div>
Expected
<div class="bar2">
  <div class="progress" style="width: 50%">
    <span>50</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you run the code snippet, you can see two progress bar, In the first progress bar, the number inside the box should be visible as shown in the second progress bar but at that exact position.
Any suggestions would be helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. `position:relative` to `.bar .progress {...}`.
> 2. `position:absolute`  and `right:0;` to `span(.first)` this will move to the last based on the position on parent i.e. `bar`.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Manju06/60r7pz3m/463/) to play around.

```css
.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #eee;
}

.bar .progress {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  /* change this make sure it works */
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4ece99;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.first {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: -12px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 28px;
  line-height: 22px;
  border: 2px solid #345;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
}

.bar2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #eee;
}

.bar2 .progress {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4ece99;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.bar2 .progress span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -58px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 28px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid #345;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
Current:
<div class="bar">
  <div class="progress">
    <span class="first">50</span>
  </div>
</div>

Expected
<div class="bar2">
  <div class="progress" style="width: 50%;">
    <span>50</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below will give your expected results. You had set the positon of bar1 span to absolute , which was centering it. Thank you.

```css
.bar {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #eee;
}

.bar .progress {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4ece99;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;


  font-size: .75rem;
}

.bar .progress span {
  position: relative;
  top: -12px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -28px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 28px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 5px;
  padding-left: 9px;
  padding-right: 9px;
  border: 2px solid #345;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
}



.bar2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4px;
  background: #eee;
}

.bar2 .progress {
  /*position: absolute;*/
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: #4ece99;
  border-radius: 16px;
  transition: width 1s ease-out;
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

.bar2 .progress span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -12px;
  left: 100%;
  margin-left: -28px;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 28px;
  line-height: 22px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 2px solid #345;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background: #fff;
}
```

```html
Current: 
<div class="bar">
  <div class="progress" style="width: 50%">
    <span>50</span>
  </div>
</div>
Expected
<div class="bar2">
  <div class="progress" style="width: 50%">
    <span>50</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: dude, lol, I need that box in the center of the progress bar. If I change the width of the progress, the box should also move its position